# Tests fail when 8th endpoint is created using generator angular-fullstack

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, angular-fullstack

The problem is as weird as the title. I have a project which I created using the generator angular-fullstack, which I am connecting to a MSSQL server using Sequelize (who the f uses MSSQL... client's demands) and everything has been working really well until I had to create the 8th endpoint (using angular-fullstack:endpoint).

Every time I created an endpoint all the test (automatically created and executed using mocha) would work except for the PATCH verb integration test, which I would just eliminate as I am not using PATCH at all.

After I created the 8th endpoint (doing the same I did for every other one) the integration tests created by the generator itself (the unit tests work perfectly) started to fail (not just the endpoint's test, but other tests that used to work before), and they fail randomly (sometimes 3 of them fail, sometimes 4, and sometimes they all work), which makes me think of some kind of race condition (which I wasn't able to find).

Findings:

- The POST integration test "works" but the result doesn't show up in the database. The log shows a correct SQL command sent to the database:
  `INSERT INTO [Findings] ([name],[info],[createdAt],[updatedAt]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (N'New Finding',N'This is the brand new finding!!!',N'2018-03-05 22:30:24.000',N'2018-03-05 22:30:24.000');`, and it returns 201 as status.
- When the status code returned is 500, the error is usually `name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  message: 'Invalid object name \'Findings\'.',` as if the Table didn't exist, but it does!

If you have any idea on what can I try, I will be more than grateful! (I have already searched everywhere I could think of, but it's even hard to search for this problem)
 This is the file containing the last-endpoint-created's tests. I can add any other file that might help to find a possible solution!

```js
'use strict';

/* globals describe, expect, it, beforeEach, afterEach */

var app = require('../..');
import request from 'supertest';

var newFinding;

describe('Finding API:', function() {
  describe('GET /api/findings', function() {
    var findings;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
      request(app)
        .get('/api/findings')
        .expect(200)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res) => {
          if(err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          findings = res.body;
          done();
        });
    });

    it('should respond with JSON array', function() {
      expect(findings).to.be.instanceOf(Array);
    });
  });

  describe('POST /api/findings', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
      request(app)
        .post('/api/findings')
        .send({
          name: 'New Finding',
          info: 'This is the brand new finding!!!'
        })
        .expect(201)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res) => {
          if(err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          newFinding = res.body;
          done();
        });
    });

    it('should respond with the newly created finding', function() {
      expect(newFinding.name).to.equal('New Finding');
      expect(newFinding.info).to.equal('This is the brand new finding!!!');
    });
  });

  describe('GET /api/findings/:id', function() {
    var finding;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
      request(app)
        .get(`/api/findings/${newFinding._id}`)
        .expect(200)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res) => {
          if(err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          finding = res.body;
          done();
        });
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      finding = {};
    });

    it('should respond with the requested finding', function() {
      expect(finding.name).to.equal('New Finding');
      expect(finding.info).to.equal('This is the brand new finding!!!');
    });
  });

  describe('PUT /api/findings/:id', function() {
    var updatedFinding;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
      request(app)
        .put(`/api/findings/${newFinding._id}`)
        .send({
          name: 'Updated Finding',
          info: 'This is the updated finding!!!'
        })
        .expect(200)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end(function(err, res) {
          if(err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          updatedFinding = res.body[0];
          done();
        });
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      updatedFinding = {};
    });

    it('should respond with the updated finding', function() {
      expect(updatedFinding).to.equal(1);
    });

    it('should respond with the updated finding on a subsequent GET', function(done) {
      request(app)
        .get(`/api/findings/${newFinding._id}`)
        .expect(200)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res) => {
          if(err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          let finding = res.body;

          expect(finding.name).to.equal('Updated Finding');
          expect(finding.info).to.equal('This is the updated finding!!!');

          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround and I think I have found the problem, but I don't understand why it is happening now, and not before.

Some tests were being executed before the db connection was established, so I have added

```js
before(function(done) {
    app.on('appStarted', function() {
      done();
    });
  });
```

to the new test file, and now it works without any problem!